# Why is the center tap of the transformer connected to the positive terminal of the 12V DC battery?

Tags: inverter

Schematic of the DC to AC inverter circuit:

[image: Schematic of the DC to AC Inverter Circuit]

Why is the center tap of the transformer connected to the positive terminal of the 12VDC battery?

Comment: Click the edit button at the bottom of your question and use the built in schematic editor and image insert function to add diagrams to better explain what you mean.

Comment: half watt resistors? you'll have trouble getting more than a 0.1W out of a 4047!

Comment: That's how a half-bridge push pull circuit like this works.

Comment: This is a classic (since the 1920s) push-pull circuit - works with vacuum tubes, NPN transistors or NMOS FETs. Only needs low side switches which are much simpler than the drive arrangements (or inferior PMOS) needed for high side switching.

Answer (score 3):

We need an alternating current through the transformer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFoR5b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. If we redraw the primary circuit like this it may become a little more clear.*

- When SW1 is closed current flows from right to left although only on half the winding.
- When SW2 is closed current flows from left to right in the other half of the winding.

The effect on the secondary is that a voltage with alternating polarity is produced. This arrangement is the simplest method of achieving that and only two "switches" are required.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using one winding and switching direction of current flow both ways with an H bridge, using the center tap of the transformer, they energise only one half of the winding at a time.  This costs extra copper in the transformer, but allows a much simpler switching arrangement without the concern of shoot through.

Comment: And possibly that transformer with a centre tap is a common product...